# Send email via crontab fails

Tags: 18.04, cron, ubuntu-mate

I put a script in crontab to send me an email when a backup script has completed.

That script when run by itself does send me that email.

However, when it runs in crontab I get

```
sendmail: 450 Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable
```

From syslog

```
Aug 15 03:49:02 7 CRON[5237]: (andy) CMD (/home/andy/bin/Send_Email.sh)
Aug 15 03:49:07 7 sSMTP[5241]: Creating SSL connection to host
Aug 15 03:49:07 7 sSMTP[5241]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Aug 15 03:49:07 7 cron[760]: sendmail: 450 Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Aug 15 03:49:07 7 sSMTP[5241]: 450 Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Aug 15 03:49:07 7 CRON[5236]: (andy) MAIL (mailed 63 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
Aug 15 03:49:46 7 gvfsd-metadata[1674]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

This is part of crontab

```
  # m h  dom mon dow   command
   # Run my backup script at 10 a.m every day
   0 10 * * * /home/andy/bin/Backup_18_04.sh
  # Run my backup script at 8 p.m every day
  0 20 * * * /home/andy/bin/Backup_18_04.sh
  0 10 * * * /home/andy/bin/Send_Email.sh
  0 20 * * * /home/andy/bin/Send_Email.sh
  30 3 * * * /home/andy/bin/Send_Email.sh
```

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
#
# Send an email using a script
# Make sure there are several blank lines between Subject and the message.!!
CONTENT="Backup to Maxtor Drive has occured."
ssmtp -t << EOF
To: fake@yahoo.com
From: fake@yahoo.com
Subject: Backups to Maxtor Drive


$CONTENT
Cheers,
   Andy
EOF
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This is not a cron error, and rather an error with your `sendmail` configuration. Make sure you have the right credentials set up

Comment: Could you give more details on credentials? And why does the script run fine by itself if I have the wrong credentials?

Comment: Perhaps your ssmtp configuration relies on something in your interactive shell environment that's not present in the cron environment (such as `$USER`)?

Comment: How would I know?

Comment: You should not run `ssmtp` directly; that is not what it's for. Use a proper MUA such as `mailx` or `mutt`.

Comment: andy@7_~/Downloads$ mailx -s "This is Subject" andrew_kennedy7@yahoo.com < Test_Email.txt
mailx: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Answer (score 1):

It may not be elegant, but it does work on my system.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
# 
# Backup sounds
cd /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/
echo yyy | sudo -S zip -u My_Sounds.zip *.mp3 *.wav
sudo zip -u My_Sounds.zip *.mp3 *.wav
# Send me email of the backup

CONTENT="Backup to Maxtor Drive has occured."
echo "Sending email."
/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t << EOF
To: joebob@yahoo.com
From: joebob@yahoo.com
Subject: Backups to Maxtor Drive


$CONTENT
Cheers,
   Andy
EOF
```